# gulp - make gulp.pipe(gulp.dest) sync

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, gulp, synchronous

I have two tasks, B depends on A.

Task A has a requirement to loop an array, then do `gulp.dest`, but seems B will execute before A's done.

What A do is to load all the html, and inject each to `template.html`

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use run-sequence for this, available via npm (see https://www.npmjs.com/package/run-sequence).

In your gulpfile it looks like this:

```
gulp.task("dist-sequence", function() {
    return runSequence("dist-clean",
        [
            "dist-client-js", "dist-vendor-js", "dist-client-css", "dist-vendor-css",
            "dist-fonts", "dist-images", "dist-template", "dist-html"
        ],
        "dist-index-inject");
});
```

All the tasks called out in `runSequence` run in the order you declare them in. Above, when I call the `dist-sequence` task, `dist-clean` runs, followed by all the tasks in the array running in parallel, and when completed, `dist-index-inject` runs.